# How many ways can an audio device be disabled, such that it doesn't appear in Pulse Audio?

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio

Back in version 16.04, I found a way to disable my laptop's only audio output device in such a way that I did not need to touch the BIOS or any of the hardware and that the only device that appears in Pulse Audio became a "Dummy Output". Now that I'm in version 18.04, I want to undo this decision. The problem is, I can't remember how I did the disabling and therefore have no idea how to (re)enable. Which leads me to this question, what are all of the possible ways that I could've done it? With any luck, I'll be able to solve this problem by brute force.

EDIT: At nik gnomic's request, I've checked the following commands.

1. `pactl list cards` returns nothing
2. `aplay -l` returns `aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...`

Comment: please post text output for command `aplay -l`for ALSA hardware devices. also output for `pactl list cards`

Comment: @nikgnomic Good idea, see edit.

Comment: I am guessing here but You probably blacklisted the kernel module that was used for this audio device. See files here `/etc/modprobe.d/*` if there is such module blacklisted.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz That's looking very plausible. Would this be a simple case of commenting out the relevant blacklist line and then rebooting? I'd be happy to do that, but I'll be even happier if I could do it without rebooting.

Comment: You need to know which module is handling Your soundcard. Then You can issue the `sudo modprobe [module-name]` to load it instantly. You probably would have to also restart PulseAudio and Alsa, so it is actually better to comment out the blacklist and just reboot.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz You're right that I blacklisted. After commenting out and rebooting, the problem is fixed. I'll have to look deeper to see how to do and undo this without rebooting.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz Interesting, modprobe is all that I need re-enable. I don't need to restart anything. All that's left to figure out is how to re-disable.

Comment: If You look to remove this module from kernel You can use `sudo modprobe -r [module-name]`.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz Good to know, but that ends up having a lot of dependencies. I've got nowhere with it.